# How do I modify the Datatable header style in PF Dynamic Columns?

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces

I'm trying to apply a css rule to the header of a datatable.
The problem is that i'm using Dynamic Columns (`<p:columnS>`), and i don't know how to apply a css rule only for the header.

When i try to set the style property for `p:column` it also change the row style.

```
<p:columns var="a" width="40" style="text-align:center;color:red" ....>
```

---

And when i try to set only the `th` on the css rule, it doesn't work:

```
<p:columns var="a" width="40" style="text-align:center" styleClass="test" ... >

.test th {
    color:red;
}
```

---

Also, i can't just make a rule like #table th {...}, because the rules of the header style depends on each dynamic column.
That would be something like:

```
<p:columns var="a" width="40" style="text-align:center" styleClass="#{a.style}" ...>

.style1{....}
```

Suggetions??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do

```
th[role=columnheader] {
     background-image: none;
     ....
}
```

Comment: Nice! All i had to do was: StyleClass="xpto" and in my css: .xpto[role=columnheader] (the `th` didn't work as expected). Thank you!

Comment: Super. You can check what styles to override with for example firebug

Comment: I just didn't know that i could use that `role=...`. It will help me a lot in the next features, thank you again.